# INamingContainer in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, inamingcontainer

We have recently upgraded to .NET 4.5 from .NET 3.5SP1. We have found that the controls using the INamingContainer interface are now rendering their ClientID differently.

MS documentation says that the INamingContainer creates a new ID namespace within a control's hierarchy.

With the old behaviour our ids would look like this:

```
<input id="MyContainer_txtName" />
```

but we now get:

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl00_c_contentHolder_MyContainer_txtName" />
```

Which has the ct100 prefix and the content holder control name in it.

An example class using this would be:

```
public class MyTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox, INamingContainer
{

}
```

We have set `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` for backwards compatibility.

We could use `ClientID="static"` to manually give each control the correct id as before but this would be a lot of work for us to complete.

I would like to understand why INamingContianer is not rendering as it previously was in the older version of .NET.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770142

Comment: Thanks Tim. ClientIDMode="AutoID" for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Does it only behave like this with controls that implement `INamingContainer`? Are controls that **are in** a `NamingContainer`(like `GridView`) prefixed as in 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using the Predictable and Static ClientModeID as described in this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx).

The bit that help me solve it is near the end.

> **The Effect Of Parent Naming Containers When Using The Predictable Setting**
>
> ....
>
> If you set the GridView's ClientIDMode to Predictable then the
>   auto-generated IDs would be removed and the row index or specified
>   data field value would be appended, resulting in ids like the
>   following:
>
> ContentPlaceHolder1_UserControlID_GridViewID_lblName_0
>   ContentPlaceHolder1_UserControlID_GridViewID_lblName_1
>   ContentPlaceHolder1_UserControlID_GridViewID_lblName_2 
>   ...
>
> Note how
>   the ContentPlaceHolder ID is still part of the rendered id. We could
>   omit this portion of the id by setting the User Control's ClientIDMode
>   to Static, which can be done via the User Control's @Control
>   directive. This would result in ids like so:
>
> UserControlID_GridViewID_lblName_0
>   UserControlID_GridViewID_lblName_1
>   UserControlID_GridViewID_lblName_2
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

The [**breaking change**](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770142) was in .NET4:

> The `ClientIDMode` setting in ASP.NET 4 lets you specify how ASP.NET
>   generates the id attribute for HTML elements. In previous versions of
>   ASP.NET, the default behavior was equivalent to the AutoID setting of
>   `ClientIDMode`. However, the default setting is **now Predictable**.
>
> If you use Visual Studio 2010 to upgrade your application from ASP.NET
>   2.0 or ASP.NET 3.5, the tool automatically adds a setting to the Web.config file that preserves the behavior of earlier versions of the
>   .NET Framework. However, if you upgrade an application by changing the
>   application pool in IIS to target the .NET Framework 4, ASP.NET uses
>   the new mode by default. To disable the new client ID mode, add the
>   following setting in the Web.config file:

```
<pages ClientIDMode="AutoID" / >
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. We are aware of this setting and it does not help to fix the problem. Ive updated my question to reflect this.